# Why do my other values in my dataset show up as NaN? (Javascript D3)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I used this function to get all my data from a CSV file:

```
    access = function(d, i, columns) {
        for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) 
        t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
        d.total = t;
        return d;
}
```

but whenever I try to access the data only the first column shows up as a string, the rest say NaN.

```
Object {SEX: "Males", GEO/ACL00: NaN, Total: NaN, Personal care: NaN, Sleep: NaN…}
```

This function is called by the following:

```
d3.csv(url, access, callback);
```

I could change the clock values to an actual value, Move the Geographical names one to the left and then change the Males to 0 and Females to 1 but I don't think I'm allowed to change my dataset for this problem.

I am using D3 to try and get a stacked bar chart composed of 24 hours each, I've looked at a few videos and sources but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Here is a link to the dataset: 
https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/eagan/class/igr204/data/TimeUse.csv

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to recreate the problem as I can't attach a CSV dataset to the code snippet, the original code won't really help but I added an extra line which shows that the code is called by d3.csv()

Comment: We don't need the full CSV dataset. Any minimal sample dataset that reproduces the problem will do.

Comment: I'm having more trouble just trying to reproduce this problem as I'm not sure how D3 takes the dataset in the first place.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like you're executing number operations on data which type is not number. You need to parse your data.